# wordpress multisite set up on localhost, redirects to live site

Tags: multisite

I tried to clone a wordpress multisite on localhost. Instead of loading `http://localhost/test.org`, requests are redirected to `test.org`. I've summarized different things I've tried to resolve this issue.

[Update: I've changed `http://localhost/test.org` to `localhost/test.org`]

In `.htaccess`, I've tried changing `RewriteEngine` from `On` to `Off`, and I've done a search and replace to change `test.org` to `localhost\test.org`.
The cache is empty.

In the database, I've updated the following tables / values, changing test.org to localhost/test.org.

- `wp_options` / `siteurl`
- `wp_options` / `home`
- `wp_site`
- `wp_sitemeta` / `siteurl`
- `wp_blogs` / `domain`
- `wp_#_options` > `siteurl` (replacing # with the number of each site in the network)
- `wp_#_options` / `home`
- `wp_#_options` / fileupload_url

In `wp-config.php`, `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` are both `localhost/test.org`.

Here's the multisite config section in `wp-config.php`:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'test.org');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

If I try to set `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` to `localhost/test.org`, I get an error message saying: "The page isn’t redirecting properly", "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

I thought that a plugin might be causing the problem, so I moved everything from `wp-content/plugins` to another folder.

I've cleared the browser cache and I've used a different browser.

Does anyone have recommendations for other steps I could try?

Comment: It's possible that Firefox has cached a redirect to `test.org`. If you update `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` and try it in a private Firefox window (or a different browser entirely), does it work as expected?

Comment: I tried a different browser, it's still redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

When moving a WordPress Multisite install to a different domain (such as from a live site to localhost), there are a few steps you need to follow to ensure that the site works correctly. These include updating the database and adjusting the wp-config.php file.

Firstly, the `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` in your `wp-config.php` file should not include '**http://**'. It should just be the domain name, so in your case it should be '**localhost**'.

And there are several places in the database where you need to change the domain. Do properly change them, you can use a [search and replace script](https://interconnectit.com/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) or you can try a search and replace plugin like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) one.

Remember to clear your browser cache before testing your site on localhost, as your browser may have cached redirects to your live site.

Then, make sure your hosts file on your local machine is set up to associate `localhost` with the local IP address.

If you still face issues, it might be related to your server configuration. For instance, if you're using Apache, ensure that your vhost file is properly configured. If you're using a tool like MAMP or XAMPP, ensure that the server software is properly configured to point to the correct directory for your site.

Comment: I've updated the database in a few more places and I've listed which tables and which values I've changed.

 Clearing my browser cache / using a different browser or a private window doesn't work. 

I'm still experiencing the same problems. The Apache vhost is configured the same way as another local wordpress site which works as expected. This site is still redirecting to the live site.